# On function success do something

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to do something after one of my functions are done

```
$.when({
    $("#success_delete_close_btn").click(function(){
        $("#new_messaage").remove();
        $('#realone').css("display","");  

        $(".modal-content").append('<button type="button" style="width: 0; height:0; margin: 0; padding: 0;" id="close" data-dismiss="modal"></button>');
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('#close').click();
        }, 100);
    })
}).then(function() {
    $('#load_content').load('php/content/allcontent.php');
});
```

Basically what I need to do is to load my div after this is success but it must be after because if I add it in code it will load div and form will be like wtf is happening I need to close my modal with id="356" but where is id="365"...

And the modal dialog hide but modal background stays...

But if I dont add this part the content will still be seen on the page.
I need to reload it before I want to remove it...

Comment: Perhaps you can try to **show** your div upon completion.

Comment: I don't need showing here because of rest of code.. Only solution for me is  to reload page but if my post is somewhere at the middle of page and user don't want to go there again to check does post exists and just to remove it..

Comment: Sorry, from your descriptions I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish, but I see a possible problem: `.css("display","");`... you should use display value `none`, or `block`/`inline` or whatever behaviour should the element have instead of empty string.